# "The System Is Entering Sleep. Sleep Reason: Application API". Windows 10 Desktop PC in Domain Environment

Tags: group-policy, domain, windows-10

I Have 1 User that her PC (Windows 10 Desktop PC in Domain Environment) going to sleep for no good reason.
in event viewer you can see Event ID 42:

"The System Is Entering Sleep.
Sleep Reason: Application API"

the Computer account is located in the same OU as the other Computer accounts and get the same group policies.
i compared her PC to my PC in Group Policy Results Wizard in GPMC.msc and we getting the same group policy that sets the Power Plan option:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xndia.png)

also to mention, all the other windows 10 PC's and doesn't going to sleep.

things i checked that i saw in forums:

1. disabled NIC power saving
2. http://itwalkthroughs.com/knowledge-base/windows-sleep-settings-dont-work/

tried it but i shouldn't as it's not a standalone Windows PC and it's part of a domain, and all other windows 10 PC's work fine, including mine.

i don't have further ideas and what to check and i tought in worst case scenario just letting our HD to publish her PC again with a new image from SCCM.

Would appreciate your help and feedback on the matter.

Comment: That is a system event log.. Look at the time it happens for reference, then check the application event log for anything interesting in the minute or so leading up to when it happens.